# WebImage returning as PNG when source file is JPG

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, image

I have this confusing problem when WebImage retrieves an image saved as ".jpg" it returns as ".png".

Here's the image of the problem:

[image: png - jpg error]

Any ideas why this is happening?

**UPDATE**: The lighthouse.jpg is one of the My Picture samples of Windows 7 and was uploaded and saved with no frills.

Here is my upload method when uploading the lighthouse.jpg which is saved with `uploadImage.SaveAs(path);`

[image: upload method]

Comment: Are you sure it's actually a JPG, and not a PNG with the wrong extension? Check the first bytes of the file to be sure...

Comment: Yes, I checked it's properties in Explorer and it is JPEG image (.jpg).

Comment: Explorer just looks at the file ending. So that won't tell you anything.

Comment: @Ron, that doesn't prove anything. Open the file and check the header

Comment: Which doesn't prove anything? I'm already reading the uploaded file's InputStream and it's reading jpeg.

Comment: The image's MIME type may be different to its file suffix. Ref. https://stackoverflow.com/a/14587821/6812820

Answer (score 1):

Without the respective image it is not possible to solve this 100% BUT the extension (in your case jpg) is by no means a guarantee that the file is actually in that file format... I suspect it is a PNG saved with the extension JPG...

Comment: If it helps, the lighthouse.jpg is one of the sample images in Windows 7. And it was uploaded and saved with no frills as HttpPostedFileBase.

Comment: @Ron on my Win7 it has 1024x768 which leads me to assume that the *no frills* seems to be wrong (your has 550x412)... either before, during or after the upload the file has been changed...

Comment: I updated my question with the upload method, and like i said i didn't do anything special to the uploaded image, just .SaveAs().

Comment: @Ron thanks... this proves the fact that it has been changed - specifically AFTER the upload (you can see it has 1024x768 in the `Index` method while it has 550x412 in the other method!).

Comment: That's in another method that processes the image which takes place AFTER getting the upload. The image was already .png to begin with (1024x768) even before processing.

Comment: @Ron sorry but you description is really confusing to me... you don't provide enough code to reproduce the behaviour AND you provide code the wrong way (screenshot) - you should provide code in the body of your question so that a copy&paste is possible...

Comment: The screenshot's purpose was to show the properties. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

The image's Mime type may be set differently to its file-suffix. Ref. https://stackoverflow.com/a/14587821/6812820