# Handler (MIME) for multimedia content not working

Tags: c#, handler, mime-types, mime

I am working with a handler that presents multimedia content in a page.

The idea is that this handler access the file and determine the type using the extension, and presenting it, the **problem** is that most of the times the **handler itself gets downloaded** and the multimedia is not presented.

Here is the code:

```
FileInfo file = new FileInfo(filePath);
byte[] bytes = new byte[file.Length];
using (FileStream fs = file.OpenRead())
{
    fs.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
}

string extension = Path.GetExtension(filePath);
string mimeDeclaration;
if (".tif" == extension)
    mimeDeclaration = "tiff";
string[] imagenes = new string[] {".jpg", ".jpeg", ".bmp", ".gif", ".png"};
if (imagenes.Any(x => x.Contains(extension)))
    mimeDeclaration = extension.Substring(1);
else
    mimeDeclaration = string.Empty;

context.Response.ClearContent();
context.Response.ClearHeaders();
context.Response.ContentType = "image/" + mimeDeclaration;
context.Response.BinaryWrite(bytes);
```

The `filePath` variable is valid.

Could you help me avoid the handler not to present the multimedia content?

Comment: What is the "Unexpected action"?

Comment: And what is the question?

Comment: the problem is that the handler.cs gets downloaded

Comment: Check `filePath` perhaps it's the wrong file.

Comment: @Bauss unfortunately that is not the case :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I get it now, when  *mimeDeclaration* is empty or WRONG then you don't get the image download.

This occurs in your code because mime types for images aren't *always* "image/" plus the file extension:

```
context.Response.ContentType = "image/" + mimeDeclaration;
```

Eg for a .jpg image it's

> image/jpeg

Otherwise it's probably because it's a tiff image in that case your else clause is setting `mimeDeclaration` back to an empty string.

Tip: detecting MIME types by file extension is less than ideal, check the way I do it here: [Alternative to FindMimeFromData method in Urlmon.dll one which has more MIME types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15300567/)

Comment: Actually there is no case of not receiving an image, because in case of a video there is another path to handle it.

Comment: But if you want a jpg it won't get served up properly because **image/jpg** is not the correct mime type. The correct mime type for a jpg is **image/jpeg**

Comment: @DanielV I trust you've tested this solution. Did it help you to solve the problem? Do you need any further assistance?

Comment: This [MIME class](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7161265/1257607) helped me improve the code.

Comment: Meh, that's crap compared to  Winista's binary analysis.

Comment: yes I agree, but this is an academic project to be delivered ASAP, means to an end..