# Check original file type using c#

Tags: c#, mime-types

I created program to check the file have original extension or not.
For ex. File.txt is original file and after that it change to File.jpeg then how to know that original file extension.

My code snippet is...

```
string filename = openFileDialog1.FileName;
        string originalFileExt = Path.GetExtension(filename);
        string type = ScanFileForMimeType(filename);
        MessageBox.Show("Mime type : " + type);

        if (type == "application/octet-stream")
        {
            type = System.Web.MimeMapping.GetMimeMapping(filename);
            MessageBox.Show(type + "");
        }

        RegistryKey key = Registry.ClassesRoot.OpenSubKey(@"MIME\Database\Content Type\" + type, false);
        object value = key != null ? key.GetValue("Extension", null) : null;
        string result = value != null ? value.ToString() : string.Empty;
        MessageBox.Show("File Extension : " + result);

private static string ScanFileForMimeType(string fileName)
    {
        try
        {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[256];
            //using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open))
            //{
            //    int readLength = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Min(256, fs.Length));
            //    fs.Read(buffer, 0, readLength);
            //}

            UInt32 mimeType = default(UInt32);
            FindMimeFromData(0, null, buffer, 256, null, 0, ref mimeType, 0);
            IntPtr mimeTypePtr = new IntPtr(mimeType);
            string mime = Marshal.PtrToStringUni(mimeTypePtr);
            Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem(mimeTypePtr);

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(mime))
                mime = "application/octet-stream";
            return mime;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return ex.ToString();
        }
    }
```

but i am not getting mime type of MS Office file like .docx, .pptx etc.

Comment: you're using system MIME types, it means if you don't have installed an app handling those mime types they will not be present...

Comment: Also, your buffer is empty, you must fill it with the content of the file.

Comment: FindMimeFromData cannot determine those Mime types [as it is limited to these (hard-coded) values](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms775147%28VS.85%29.aspx#Known_MimeTypes) - see eg http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15300567/alternative-to-findmimefromdata-method-in-urlmon-dll-one-which-has-more-mime-typ

Comment: An interesting but different approach would be to check the files themselves. If you know the range of file types you might encounter, this could be beneficial. See http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/85054/guessing-a-file-type-based-on-its-content

Comment: I don't think you can find out if it was a txt file because a txt is just this: Some data and interpret that as readable text. It has no header or footer or anything else. The only thing I can imagine is if you cant determine the type, you should default to txt.