# file validation - content type or extension?

Tags: asp.net

I need to validate if a file is an image. 
Should I check **content type** or **extension**? What is more safe / better?
I think checking extension is better - what do you think?

```
string ext = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(fileName).ToLower();
```

Comment: Neither, as both are user-supplied. See [Determine if uploaded file is image (any format) on MVC](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11063900/determine-if-uploaded-file-is-image-any-format-on-mvc).

Answer (score 2):

If all you care for is IMAGE files, then **Content-Type** is the way to go.

But...

If you DO care for Image type, then you must check by **extension**, since there really is no true mapping from a *content-type* to the *file extension*. For example a content-type of *"image/jpeg"* could be mapped to either *.jpg* or *.jpeg*.

> However, if you're talking about checking files uploaded by users, both methods are *not* safe since they rely on user input. See [OWASP: Unrestricted File Upload](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Unrestricted_File_Upload).