# Verify uploaded file is an image

Tags: c#, image, upload, .net-core

I will be accepting user uploads on a new website in .NET Core 1.0.1. I only want to allow images, however, not just any file. How can I perform this verification in .NET Core? Is it possible to do without `System.Drawing`, as it is not implemented?

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14587821/1672458) looks promising, but it ultimately uses `System.Drawing`. Is it enough to check the content type and extension?

---

**EDIT:** The accepted answer is what I needed, but I'll share my actual implementation here. I'm doing this in .NET Core but I'm pretty sure the same code works on the full framework.

```
static bool IsJpeg(Stream stream)
{
    using (var br = new BinaryReader(stream))
    {
        var soi = br.ReadUInt16();
        var marker = br.ReadUInt16();
        return soi == 0xd8ff && (marker & 0xe0ff) == 0xe0ff;
    }
}

static bool IsPng(Stream stream)
{
    using (var br = new BinaryReader(stream))
    {
        var soi = br.ReadUInt64();
        return soi == 0x0a1a0a0d474e5089;
    }
}

static bool IsGif(Stream stream)
{
    using (var br = new BinaryReader(stream))
    {
        var soi = br.ReadUInt32();
        var p2 = br.ReadUInt16();

        return soi == 0x38464947 && (p2 == 0x6137 || p2 == 0x6139);
    }
}
```

Comment: "Is it enough to check the content type and extension?" -- What problem are you trying to solve or avoid? I can rename `virus.exe` to `normalPicture.jpg` and upload it to your site, checking the extension won't stop that (and I don't know what sets the content type, whatever sets it probably just looks at the extension too and does not "read" the file to determine it).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not enough to just check the file extension.  I could make a ZIP file, and then just renamed the extension to `.jpg` and you'd assume it was a valid file.

Image formats do have "magic bytes" at the start of them that you could use to potentially identify that a file is, in fact, an image.  [This Wikipedia entry here has a list of magic numbers you could check against](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_file_signatures).

Note also that the content-type can be spoofed.

So you have 2 things you can do.  The content-type as specified in the original answer, combined with checking the "magic numbers" of the file.  If someone really wants to upload duff data that is not an image and bypassed both these checks, you might have to do something else.

So, you have 3 known guards you can implement:

1. Does the file have an extension on your whitelist? (.jpg/.jpeg/etc...)
2. Does the content-type match an entry on your whitelist? (image/jpeg)
3. Once you've ascertained which kind of file it is via the first 2 steps, do the magic numbers match also?

Comment: This is perfect. Thank you!

Comment: @vaindil  Were you able to apply this to ASP.NET Core as there is no drawing class? Can you share what you achieved? Thanks

Comment: @ZainAlabdinTawfiq I just added my implementation to the question itself.