# determine if uploaded file is image on asp.net core

Tags: c#, asp.net, image, asp.net-core, razor

Hello friends I want when a photo from the view to the controller
It was sent to check that there must be a photo and the malicious file has not been uploaded
Just like the answers sent to this question
[Determine if uploaded file is image (any format) on MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11063900/determine-if-uploaded-file-is-image-any-format-on-mv)

But this is for MVC but I want for asp.net core

Answer (score 0):

You can achive this using Image File Headers To Verify Image Format [details](https://web.archive.org/web/20090302032444/http://www.mikekunz.com/image_file_header.html)
. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/210650/validate-image-from-file-in-c-sharp/9446045#9446045) answer will give you more details about the file header identification technique.